# What is the default background color for selected text?

Tags: background, pseudo-element

I want to make a some text always look like it is selected, even when it is not, but I cannot find the background color for selected text. If anyone knows, please tell me the rgba color for selected text. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is HEX #3390ff, RGB(51,144,255), CMYK(80,44,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to change the background color, you should change the text color by adding this class for always look like it is selected `.selected{color: #609;}`

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know the default color to do that, so it looks like normal selected text.

Comment: Already mentioned in previous post's links referring to the current document may be considered as visited if all belongs to same address other wise you can try this `a:active { color: #C00; background: transparent }
:link { color: #00C; background: transparent }
:visited { color: #609; background: transparent }`